# Overlay in Bootstrap 4 figure-img only

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add overlay to bootstrap 4 **figure-img** only. To do that I added div with **overlay** class under **figure-img**

**here is my code:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <figure class="service text-center">
    <img src="img/service1.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid w-100" alt="Repair Request Service">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
      <h4>Repair Request Service</h4>
      <p>We care about you and your vehicle. We want to make sure whether you see us for an auto repair or a scheduled maintenance, that we</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Read More</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS is like this:**

```
.services .figure-img {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: #f00;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}
.service:hover .overlay {
    display:block;
    opacity: .3;
}
```

But the overlay is consuming full width including **col-md-4** right and left padding. and displaying like this:

[image]

How to solve this problem and put overlay in **.figure-img** properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I added a div with **svcimg** class and put **.figure-img & .overlay** inside it.

**Here is my new HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <figure class="service text-center">
    <div class="svcimg">
      <img src="img/service6.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid w-100" alt="Erection on Metal Build">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
      <h4>Referrals Service</h4>
      <p>Customer referral is our most popular form of advertising. We greatly appreciate the confidence of your referral. To show our gratitude</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Read More</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
.services .service .svcimg {
    position: relative;
}

.services .service .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #f41004;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f41004 0%, #207cca 100%, #3557f3 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f41004 0%,#207cca 100%,#3557f3 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f41004 0%,#207cca 100%,#3557f3 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f41004', endColorstr='#3557f3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.services .service:hover .overlay {
    opacity: .5;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

**And Here is the Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`.overlay` in your example is positioned relative to `.col-md-4`.

Add `position: relative;` to `.service` - that way `.overlay` would work as you expect.

```css
.service .figure-img {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.service {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #f00;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.service:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-4">
  <figure class="service text-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/600" class="figure-img img-fluid w-100" alt="Repair Request Service">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
      <h4>Repair Request Service</h4>
      <p>We care about you and your vehicle. We want to make sure whether you see us for an auto repair or a scheduled maintenance, that we</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Read More</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to have overlay over *only* `img`, not whole `figure` - then you need to add some wrapper for `img` and put `.overlay` inside.

```css
.service .figure-img {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #f00;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.service:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-4">
  <figure class="service text-center">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/600" class="figure-img img-fluid w-100" alt="Repair Request Service">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
      <h4>Repair Request Service</h4>
      <p>We care about you and your vehicle. We want to make sure whether you see us for an auto repair or a scheduled maintenance, that we</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Read More</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Overlay is still consuming full height. I just want to display overlay in .figure-img only

Comment: @MilanBastola Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks mate, This is exactly what I did too. please see my answer too.